# Python can't start new thread, but not hitting thread limit

Tags: linux, multithreading, python-3.x, embedded-linux, python-multithreading

I've got an embedded system (armv5tejl AT91SAM9X25 with 128MB RAM running a buildroot-based rootfs) with Python 3 installed. I've left the system running for many days now and I've come to do some python development work on it, but seem to run into a problem creating new threads.

If I try to run the following program:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import threading
>>> import time
>>> def func():
...     i = 0
...     while True:
...         i += 1
...         print(i)
...         time.sleep(1)
...
>>>
>>> func()
1
2
3
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in func
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> t = threading.Thread(target=func)
>>> t.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 850, in start
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
>>>
```

As you can see, when trying to start the thread, I get the above error. Some initial searching online seems to indicate that the problem may be due to the system running into thread limits. Here is the output of ulimit -a:

```
# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 961
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 961
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Using [this method](https://superuser.com/a/547043/132615), the total number of threads on my system is 75, which is way below the limit of 961. Here is my current memory status:

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           120        118          2         60          0         65
-/+ buffers/cache:         52         67
Swap:            0          0          0
```

I've also run the memory compactor by running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/compact_memory`.

I imagine that everything would work fine if I rebooted the device (since the code is known working code), but since I have the device in this state right now, I'm keen on trying to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It may just be that threading isn't enabled in your Python implementation. It's one of the more troublesome areas for developers. Who provided the Python, and have they any documentation at all on their threading implementation?

Comment: Threading is definitely enabled, as I've written Python software on the unit that uses threads. It's just that now, running that software fails because the interpreter can't create the thread.

Comment: I've hit this same problem in an environment where threading works great for a while. And every so often this happens. Would be great to know if there is a cause besides hitting 256 threads